# which is the best solution for webcam streaming?

Tags: performance, streaming, video-streaming

I would like to create a streaming cam2cam for adult website and wondering what would be the best solution for video and sound quality.I do not have experience in this area so not want to  use something like node.js or something like this.

Comment: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out **Nimbb**. You can quickly and easily add webcam recording and streaming features into any website / webpage. It's been around for a while and I saw their demo in San Francisco way back in 2010. http://nimbb.com/